# I do not know 'glibc detected' in C

Tags: c, unix, glibc

when I end my program, I found 'glibc detected' message like this.
However, I do not know this is error or warning or else.. could someone explain what this message meaning and how I have to do?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code please? It would help..

Comment: The error is not "glibc detected", but rather what follows that message. Let's see some code. (Oh and, for the future: a picture isn't really a suitable way to convey textual information).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you have heap corruption in your program.  You likely allocate some memory using `malloc`, but write outside the actual bounds, corrupting the heap.  When you call `free`, glibc detects the corruption and reports it (specifically, the size of the next free chunk is overwritten).

You should definitely fix this problem.  [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) can be a huge help in tracking down the code that actually causes the heap corruption.

Answer (score 4):

You've corrupted the heap somewhere in your program. You may have written outside memory you got using `realloc` and `malloc`. But then when you tried to free the memory, the `malloced` memory was freed, but the memory you wrote out of bounds too was not, this leads to the corruption error you get. There are a few tools such as: [Debugging for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) as well as [electricfence](http://perens.com/FreeSoftware/ElectricFence/), [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/), [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Also, you may want to check your loops in because its possible a simple `while loop` or a `for loop` is causing the error due to not checking the bounds or limits properly in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You corrupted the heap, so you made a mistake somewhere regarding memory management; use a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find and fix such errors.